# Sow divisibility with congruence equation

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, congruence-relations

I have this math question that I'm kind of stuck on.

> Suppose that the congruence equation $ax \equiv b \pmod{n}$ has at
>    least one solution.  Let $d = \gcd{(a, n)}$. Show that $d \mid b$.

I know that $ax \equiv b\pmod{n}\implies ax-nm=b$ for some integer $m$. However, I'm not totally sure how to finish this. Thanks.

Comment: Since $d$ divides $a$ and $d$ divides $n$, we conclude that $d$ divides $ax-nm$. So from your equation we see that  $d$ divides $b$.

Answer (score 0):

$\{ua+vn\mid u,v\in\mathbf Z\}\;$ is the set of multiples of $\gcd(a,n)$.